# Android graphic effects entire canvas

Tags: android, graphics, blur, android-canvas

I am writing my own 2D game for android. So far I've been using some home brew graphics - drawing frame-by-frame on a canvas with a surfaceview. I've been able to draw a variety of lines, shapes and bitmaps with solid performance.

I am wondering if it is possible (or if anyone has clever ideas) to apply certain effects to an entire canvas. For instance, it would be cool if I could add some changing gaussian blur effect to simulate movement. I have found tutorials on how to apply a gaussian blur to a bitmap, but I need to apply it to my entire canvas (which is made up of a bitmap with shapes drawn in front of it).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Once something is renderer in the hardware backbuffer, it's very hard to get access to it, it's slow, if not entirely impossible.

The standard way to make a performant post process effect is to render everything in an image or texture you created yourself. You then apply whatever effect you want to that texture, or use that texture to render in the back buffer using your effect.

Comment: I was thinking there was some way to use a drawFilter or apply a matrix to the canvas to get an effect like this?